# Mostrar un PDF en un WebView android

Tags: android

Como podría mostrar un PDF en un WebView si el PDF lo tengo en un BitMap ?

Lo que tengo es esto:

- obtengo un String que llega en un WebService, llega en un formato de este tipo: yMDcgMCBSIDIwOSAwIFIgMjExIDAgUiAyMTMgMCBSI

Esto es una cadena muy larga es solo un ejemplo, despues lo paso a un BitMap para poderlo pasar en un Intent a otra actividad.

```
byte[] arrDocumento = Base64.decode(catalogoSeleccionado.getDocto(), 
 Base64.DEFAULT);

 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrDocumento, 
     0, arrDocumento.length);
```

Después de pasarlo a la actividad quiero mostrarlo en un WebView, es un documento de tipo PDF, pero aun no logro hacer que se visualice y solo he encontrado ejemplos de como mostrarlos si el pdf esta en una URL.

Comment: Revisa este link, no necesitas pasar tu data en b64 a bitmap,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498937/android-display-pdf-received-bytes-from-service-in-web-view-in-android

Comment: como le estas pasando el pdf al webView?

Comment: Si el pdf lo tienes en un bitmap, en este caso puedes cargar el Bitmap en el WebView

Comment: Gracias revisare el link @dieg

Comment: @David Aun no lo paso , lo intente con load me parece pero no lo carga

Comment: @Jorgesys El dato original es un String ese String lo paso a un byte[] para posteriormente pasarlo a un Bitmap, esto es por que ese dato lo tengo de una lista y luego el usuario selecciona un elemento de esa lista y cuando da click lo mando a otra pantalla, y pues ese dato al pasarlo en un Intent como parámetro pues no me deja pasarlo a menos que sea un Bitmap ya que es demasiado grande como String o como byte[] para pasarlo como parámetro, por eso hago la conversión en mi ejemplo